# How to create the 'certificate policies' extension in pyOpenSSL?

Tags: certificate, pyopenssl, policies

Creating 'certificate policies' extension in pyOpenSSL can be hardly found in the Internet.

I try like this: crypto.X509Extension('certificatePolicies',True,'Policy: 2.16.840.1.114414.1.7.23.3,CPS: ttp://certificates.starfieldtech.com/repository/')

But, error like this: OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('X509 V3 routines', 'DO_EXT_NCONF', 'no config database'), ('X509 V3 routines', 'X509V3_EXT_nconf', 'error in extension')] occurred.

So, can anyone tell me how to do it correctly? How to create 'config database'?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Gaston Can you help me?

Comment: I have solved the problem adding 'policy mapping' extension. @Gaston How to add 'certificate policies' using Python?